# Can I remove all the recent kernel versions at /lib/modules/

Tags: directory, kernel-modules, fhs

I saw that in `/lib/modules/` I have 7 directories that related to the out of date kernel versions, can I fully delete them? It will not make any changes or hurt my system?

```
$ ls /lib/modules
5.4.0-26-generic  5.4.0-31-generic  5.4.0-37-generic  5.4.0-40-generic
5.4.0-29-generic  5.4.0-33-generic  5.4.0-39-generic  5.4.0-42-generic
$ uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic # remove all directories without this kernel directory
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should run

```
dpkg -S /lib/modules/*
```

to check whether any installed package matches those directories. You can delete any directory for which the above says

```
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/modules/...
```

For directories still matching a package, you should remove the corresponding package first. If you’re using Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

should [take care of this for you](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels), but do pay attention to the list of packages it shows before confirming the removal.

Comment: The first command just output `inux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-31-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-31-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-33-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-37-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic
linux-modules-5.4.0-39-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-40-generic, linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic, linux-modules-5.4.0-40-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic, linux-modules-extra-5.4.0`, etc. for all of them

Comment: That means you still have kernel packages installed for all the module directories listed; try the last command in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it is does not remove my old kernels. By the way, I tried to use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it is not upgrading my kernel to the latest version. But I think that I will accept the answer because it answers my first question.

Comment: Oh, that’s strange. You should at least be able to manually remove the old kernel packages (`sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generc linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic` etc.).

Comment: I will try that fam, thanks for the help

Comment: The deletable directories should only contain a few hundred bytes; the ones to keep contain a couple of hundred **Megabytes** - assuming generic kernels and that the corresponding kernel-image have been cleanly removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that distills the results of the command [posted by @Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/605809/137608)

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/modules/* 2>&1 | grep "no path found matching pattern" | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr "\n" " "
```

getting a clean list of all "target" directories,
so you can chain it with something like

```
$ rmdir $(dpkg -S /lib/modules/* 2>&1 | grep "no path found matching pattern" | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr "\n" " ")
```

or the more radical

```
$ rm -rf $(dpkg -S /lib/modules/* 2>&1 | grep "no path found matching pattern" | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr "\n" " ")
```

Now this leads me to a further question...

Comment: Thanks for this.. This works too `dpkg -S /lib/modules/* 2>&1 | grep -v "no path found matching pattern" | awk '{ print $NF}' | xargs -I % echo %` replace echo with rm -rv to remove.

Comment: I think its strange that I can use `dpkg -S /lib/modules/* | grep -v dpkg-query` to remove the "no path.." line.